# CSS Fullscreen background does work in Dev-tools but not in real browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fullscreen

I have built a Meteor App/Website and I am trying to have a responsive fullscreen background image at the top of this page (https://www.conducate.com).

It works as expected in the Chrome Developer tools as well as in the Safari Responsive Design mode, but when I deploy the page and look at it on my mobile, it seems to zoom into the top part of the image, and does not resize it as expected from the dev-tools. As a result, there is just a grey blur to see.

Has any of you come across this problem before? It is hard to debug, since it works correctly in all the developer tools, but not at all when actually viewed on a mobile device.

Below is a link to an image with screenshots, one from my mobile (iPhone 6s, safari browser) and the other from the safari responsive design mode on my mac. Unfortunately, I am unable to post an image due to lack of reputation, so I can just post the link - I am still a newbie here...

https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/conducate-images/stackoverflow/example_screenshots.png

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What phone are you using ?

Comment: I am using an iPhone 6s and I have the issue with chrome and safari on that phone

Comment: Do you think you can make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know which component causes the issue. So I thought posting a link to the website would help, since I could not replicate the issue without deploying something because the problem does not show inside the developer tools

Comment: No special issue on Android. At least post a screenshot. Remove your URL if you are restricted by reputation privilege, or go get some reputation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The fact that it works on android gives me something to google for. I will let you know if something turns up. I have added a link to a pair of screenshots above - you are right about my lack of reputation. Will definitely work on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching for iOS specific issues, I finally came across the solution to the problem by looking at some other examples.

It turns out, that most browsers understand the css line

```
.container{
   background: url(http://www.link-to-image.jpg)
   ...
}
```

This is not the case for iOS, here you need to specifically state that it is an image, that is used for a background.

```
.container{
 background-image: url(http://www.link-to-image.jpg)
 ...
}
```